# Why Xamarin.Form CollectionView doesn't show the binding data in WPF platform?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to learn Xamarin.Form in Android and WPF platforms. I am using a very simple observable collection as data binding in a ViewModel file. Data binding works properly in Android platform, but it doesn't show anything in WPF platform! Other controls like buttons and labels work correctly in WPF platform. In debugging mode the button which fills the collection also works when I start WPF as default project.

ViewModel file codes

```
public sealed class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Test { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public Command LoadCommand { get; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        LoadCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Test.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        });

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml file codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Select one of the items below."
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"
        Text="test" />

    <CollectionView
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not for WPF as of now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I search some info about using Collectionview in WPF, but from this [collectionview article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction), we can see that **CollectionView is available on iOS and Android, but is only partially available on the Universal Windows Platform**, so I think it doesn't works in WPF.

But If you can use ListView to replace CollectionView, it can works fine when you using Binding.

About  adding a WPF project to a Xamarin.Forms solution, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf

This is sample :

https://github.com/techierathore/TrXamGuide